# How to get text nested between br tags without elements/classes in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm looking to pluck out Wayne County EDA in my nodejs/cheerio scraping script.

So far I can get the email (a) and name (strong) but am having trouble tracking down how I can grab the Wayne County EDA as it's not in a tag. Is there a way to say "grab text after first br tag", or is there a better way entirely to achieve it?

[image]

For reference, here's some semi working code

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.wvedc.org/members/regular-members/';

rp(url)
  .then(function (html) {
    //success!
    let length = $('div.content_page_content_text div strong', html).length;
    let results = [];
    let array = $('div.content_page_content_text div', html).get();
    array.forEach((el) => {
      results.push({
        email: $(el).find('div a').text(),
        name: $(el).find('div strong').text(),
        //company: $(el).find('div br'), // need wayne county here
      });
    });

  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    //handle error
  });
```

Edit: dang, may be a duplicate: [target text after br tag using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510646/target-text-after-br-tag-using-cheerio)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a perfect answer to the question but this is a working Solution for what you want to achieve

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://www.wvedc.org/members/regular-members/';

rp(url)
    .then(function (html) {
        //success!
        let length = $('div.content_page_content_text div strong', html).length;
        let results = [];
        let array = $('div.content_page_content_text div', html).get();
        array.forEach((el) => {
            results.push({
                email: $(el).find('div a').text(),
                name: $(el).find('div strong').text(),
                company: $(el).html().split("<br>")[1].substr(1)
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle error
    });
```